# How To Find 2nd or any other order,say 3rd, 4th, non repeating character in a string?

Tags: java, collections

Suppose i have a string named as " statistic ".

I want to print "c" as the 2nd non repeating character as the first character is `a`.

I did printed the first character but couldn't find way to traverse another keys through that?

Also, If it is given "statistic non" , can i get " c and o" too as all non repeating if, specified, leaving first and also, if specified, " a,c and o" taking all??

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You wrote, that you could determine the first letter, which is not repeted. Remove the first occurence from the string and repeat the action (wrapped into a loop).

Comment: Not Clear buddy,.

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over the string and put the occurrence of each character in a map with the key is the character, and the value is an object which has two attributes the number of occurence and the first occurence position.

Then you simple sort the keySet() of this map depending on the position and iterate over the sorted set till u find an object with only one occurence

```
   for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
       if(map.get(str.chatAt(i))==null) {
           map.put(str.charAt(i),new Wrapper(i,1)) ;
        } else {
           map.get(str.charAt(i)).occurence++;
        }

   }



     class Wrapper {
        public int occurrence;
        public int position;
        public Wrapper(int position,int occurrence) {

        this.position = position;
        this.occurrence = occurrence;
       }


      }
```

Comment: that only  I am unable to ascertain..I am using HashMap ,
for( i=0;i<str.length();i++)
  {
   c=str.charAt(i);
   
   if(map.get(c) == 1)
    return c;
   
  }

So it is returning me with the 1st key.

Comment: I will edit my answer with some snippet code to give you a start

Comment: Hope that would be usefull

Answer (score 0):

Use [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. ... This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). *Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map.*

With this, it becomes easy:

```
// We keep only a map of between tha char and the number of
// occurrences. We don't store the positions for the next (after first)
// occurrences, but the LinkedHashMap guarantees that
// the iteration order is the same as  insertion order
// (so first inserted letters will appear first when iterating)
LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> charOccurs=new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(char c : str) {
  Integer occ=charOccurs.get(c);
  if(null==occ) {
    occ=0;
  }
  else {
    occ=new Integer(occ.intValue()+1);
  }
  // "Note that insertion order is not affected 
  // if a key is re-inserted into the map."
  // Niiice!
  charOccurs.put(c, occ);
}

int order=1;
for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : charOccurs.entrySet()) {
  // this works because ...
  // "This linked list defines the iteration ordering,
  // which is normally the order in which keys were inserted"
  // Doubly-nice!!!
  if(1==entry.getValue()) { // single occurrence
    System.out.println("Char: "+entry.getKey()+" order: "+order);
    order++; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will like to go through old skool method

```
String intitialString = "statistic non";
        int count = 0;
        char[] ch = intitialString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ch.length; j++) {
                if (ch[i] == ch[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > 1) {
                count = 0;
            } else
                System.out.println(ch[i]);
        }
```

**output**

```
a
c
o
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks..
I was looking towards how to do this by Collection.

Comment: sure I'll do that way too

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippets help to identify the nonrepeating character in the string and will return the 2nd one on that.

```
public String printNonRepeatingChar(String data){

    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> counter = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    if(data!=null) {
        for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++) {
            String key = data.charAt(i)+"";
            if(counter.keySet().contains(key)) {
                Integer value = counter.get(key);
                value+=1;
                counter.put(key, value);
            }else {
                counter.put(key, 1);
            }
        }   
    }

    List<String> elements = new LinkedList<>();
    for(String key:counter.keySet()) {
        if(counter.get(key)==1) {
            elements.add(key);
        }
    }
    
    return elements.get(1);

}
```

Change the index position from 0 to length in the return statement for the nonrepeating character position. please handle the exception if index is not found.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "abhi  av ";
    char[] str = name.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char r = '\0';
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length; j++) {
            if (str[i] == str[j]) {
                str[i] = str[j] = r;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        {
            if (str[i] != '\0') {
                count++;
                if (count == 2)
                    System.out.println(str[i]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I felt this is easy method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).